# partial keyword / n gram search in drupal

Tags: drupal

how does one implement partial keyword search in drupal since by default drupal does not search for partial keywords.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. If you want to search on a single field, you can create a view with an exposed filter and set it to "contains" that will allow partial keyword searching.
2. You can also patch the core search module, which is going to make maintenance a pain in the backside later on. Patch at http://drupal.org/node/103548 .
3. The Porter Stemmer module attempts to extrapolate partial searches into full keyword matches (http://drupal.org/project/porterstemmer)
4. For real fine-grained control over search, you'll need to ditch the Drupal core search functionality completely and upgrade to Apache SOLR search, which is exceptionally powerful but requires a fair amount of configuration.
5. You can also drop Drupal search entirely and use a Google Custom Search Engine if you just want to do text matches across the site (http://drupal.org/project/google_cse)

Comment: Just a note that the Google CSE does not really do partial or substring matching.  So Solr or other search tools are a much better idea.

Comment: The Porter Stemmer is English-specific, and non-English content will not be stemmed correctly